# Programmatically change the state of a UIButton

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uibutton

I've got a pop-up view that loads when a user clicks on a TableView with Core Data elements. On the pop-up view I have a label that represents an int value.

The pop-up view has two butons, one for decreasing the value of the label by 1 and one for increasing it by one. So + and -

What I want to do is to disable the minus button if the label's value is 0. What I've tried is:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
     NSString *daString = currentVal.text;
        NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
        NSNumber * myNumber = [f numberFromString:daString];
        int number = [myNumber intValue];
        if (number==0)
            minus.enabled = NO;
        else
            minus.enabled = YES
}
```

The problem with my code is that the button stays disabled after I increase the label's value, and it's no longer equal to 0.
Any suggestions?

Comment: How exactly is this not working? Is it still receiving touch events or it looks like it is still enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep a reference to minus button e.g.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *minusButton;
```

Set it with a value of your minus button, or connect outlet in Interface Builder

in your action handler for plusButton, do something like that

```
-(IBAction)plusAction:(id)sender {
     //Do your business logic
     ...
     self.minusButton.enabled = YES;
}
//In your minusButton action handler
-(IBAction)minusAction:(id)sender {
     //Do your business logic
     ...
     NSString *daString = currentVal.text;
     NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
     [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
     NSNumber * myNumber = [f numberFromString:daString];
     int number = [myNumber intValue];
     if (number==0)
        self.minusButton.enabled = NO;
     else
        self.minusButton.enabled = YES
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have things the other way around. I would take a totally different approach:

Keep an instance variable (which we'll call 'count') in this viewController which holds the number. it can be an NSInteger. now add a target (self) to both buttons with a @selector(buttonPressed:). now this is how this selector should look like:

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender{
    if (sender==plusButton)
        self.count++;
    if (sender==minusButton)
        self.count--;
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",self.count];
    minusButton.enabled = (self.count>0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just do this with a [UIStepper](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStepper_Class/Reference/Reference.html), instead of the 2 buttons.  You can set properties right in your storyboard/IB file that specify the max and min, increments, and a bunch of other useful things too.  There are a couple video tutorials posted on [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=uistepper&oq=uistepper&gs_l=youtube.3..0.1915.3983.0.4162.9.6.0.3.3.0.187.617.5j1.6.0...0.0...1ac.1.ZBbBQ0kQvzw) that probably cover everything you'll need to know to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Also, I have noticed one thing that...
If the button in disabled state and you are trying to change the title of normal state, it wont work.
I had to change the state to enabled and then I could manipulate title and set back to disabled.